# Output precision

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I've solved some equations using `FindRoot` and then computed some values. Now when I print the output, I only get a certain precision

> {{0.01, 496.983, 61.3147, 80., 0.047},
>   {0.02, 496.983, 61.3147, 80., 0.047},
>   {0.03, 496.983, 61.3147, 80., 0.047},
>   ...
>   {0.18, 496.97, 61.3142, 80., 0.047001},
>   {0.19, 496.969, 61.3141, 80., 0.0470011},
>   {0.2, 496.968, 61.3141, 80., 0.0470012}}

But when I copy and past the individual numbers, say the 61.3147 in the first two rows, I get

> 61.314699633952216`
>   61.31469210981553`

What can I do to increase the precision of the visible output so I can eyeball it?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OutputFormatsForNumbers.html

Comment: @Oleksandr: Appearance > Numbers > Formatting > Displayed Precision

Comment: If you don't want to change the global display, you may also try `InputForm`.(For example, `InputForm@RandomReal[{1, 5}, 10]`)

Comment: As a simple workaround, you can just edit the output cell (e.g. add a single space to it).  This'll show the full number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must set the option PrintPrecision to a higher value (The default is 6 digits).

- This can be done with the Option Inspector very easily.
- This can also be done programmatically :

  `SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], PrintPrecision -> 16]`
- It works too with `Style[]`:

  `Style[N[\[Pi]], PrintPrecision -> 10]`

  -->  3.141592654 (instead of default 6 digits :3.14159)