# How can I increase the precision of my table?

Tags: list-manipulation, precision-and-accuracy

I want to see first 15 digits for the values in the table computed below.

```
n = 0; a = 1; L = 3; m = 1/2; b = 1; g = (2 m a r)/(n + L + 1);

Fi[r_] = (r)^(L + 1)Exp[-((  m a)/(n + L + 1)) r] LaguerreL[n, 2 L + 1, g];

f[r_] = AiryAi[(2 m b)^(1/3) (r)];

ψ[r_] = Fi[r] f[r];

Plot[{r^(L + 1) f[r], Fi[r] f[r]}, {r, 0, 5}]
```

[image: plot]

```
dr = 0.00000001;

ε1 = (a/(L + 1) - (L + 1)/(m r)) f'[r]/f[r] + (-m a^2)/(2 (n + L + 1)^2);
ε2 = -ψ''[r]/((2 m) ψ[r]) + (-(a/r) + b r + (L (L + 1))/(2 m r^2));

data = Table[{r, r^(L + 1) f[r], ψ[r], ε1, ε2}, {r, 2.647, 2.648, dr}];

TableForm[data, 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"r", "r^(L+1) f[r]", "Fi[r] f[r]", "ε1", "ε2"}}]
```

[image: table]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3736/annoying-display-truncation-of-numerical-results

Answer (score 4):

```
TableForm[Take[data, 5], 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"r", "r^(L+1) f[r]", "Fi[r] f[r]", 
     "\[CurlyEpsilon]1", "\[CurlyEpsilon]2"}}] //
 Style[#, PrintPrecision -> 15] &
```

[image]

**EDIT**

`PrintPrecision -> 15` can be set at the Notebook level.
See [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24968/5467) .

Comment: thank you so much sir. You have been very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
NumberForm[TableForm[data,
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"r", "r^(L+1) f[r]", "Fi[r] f[r]", 
     "\[CurlyEpsilon]1", "\[CurlyEpsilon]2"}}],
 {15, 15}]
```

[image]

**Update**

With `dr = 0.00000001` the first 10 items would be

[image]

Comment: apparently, the question was first posted with `dr`=10^-4. Now it is 10^-8